# Strange compiler error in MSVC10

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11

I've got the following code:

```
std::for_each(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), [&](Token& t) {
    static const std::unordered_map<std::wstring, Wide::Lexer::TokenType> mapping([]() -> std::unordered_map<std::wstring, Wide::Lexer::TokenType>
    {
        // Maps strings to TokenType enumerated values
        std::unordered_map<std::wstring, Wide::Lexer::TokenType> result;

        // RESERVED WORD
        result[L"namespace"] = Wide::Lexer::TokenType::Namespace;
        result[L"for"] = Wide::Lexer::TokenType::For;
        result[L"while"] = Wide::Lexer::TokenType::While;
        result[L"do"] = Wide::Lexer::TokenType::Do;
        result[L"type"] = Wide::Lexer::TokenType::Type;

        // PUNCTUATION
        result[L"{"] = Wide::Lexer::TokenType::OpenCurlyBracket;
        result[L"}"] = Wide::Lexer::TokenType::CloseCurlyBacket;
        return result;
    }());
    if (mapping.find(t.Codepoints) != mapping.end()) {
        t.type = mapping.find(t.Codepoints)->second;
        return;
    }
    t.type = Wide::Lexer::TokenType::Identifier; // line 121
});
```

This iterates through a list of tokens, and judging by the contents of the codepoints, assigns them a value from the associated enum. If it's not found, then give it a value of "Identifier". But this fails to compile.

```
1>Lexer.cpp(121): error C2065: '__this' : undeclared identifier
1>Lexer.cpp(121): error C2227: left of '->Identifier' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
```

This is the *full* error, no warnings, no other errors. What? How can I fix this error?

Edit: I did some significant refactoring, and I've got the exact same problem in a somewhat simpler lambda.

```
auto end_current_token = [&] {
    if (current != Wide::Lexer::Token()) {

        current.type = Wide::Lexer::TokenType::Identifier; // error line

        if (reserved_words.find(current.Codepoints) != reserved_words.end())
            current.type = reserved_words.find(current.Codepoints)->second;
        if (punctuation.find(current.Codepoints[0]) != punctuation.end())
            current.type = punctuation.find(current.Codepoints[0])->second;

        tokens.push_back(current);
        current = Wide::Lexer::Token();
    }
};
```

I've cleaned and rebuilt the project.

I fixed the problem.

```
auto end_current_token = [&] {
    if (current != Wide::Lexer::Token()) {

        // WORKAROUND compiler bug- dead code
        struct bug_workaround_type {
            int Identifier;
        };
        bug_workaround_type bug;
        bug_workaround_type* __this = &bug;

        current.type = Wide::Lexer::TokenType::Identifier;

        if (reserved_words.find(current.Codepoints) != reserved_words.end())
            current.type = reserved_words.find(current.Codepoints)->second;
        if (punctuation.find(current.Codepoints[0]) != punctuation.end())
            current.type = punctuation.find(current.Codepoints[0])->second;

        tokens.push_back(current);
        current = Wide::Lexer::Token();
    }
};
```

No, really. Now it compiles and runs just fine.

Comment: @NicolBolas: It's commented- the second-to-last line.

Comment: What class is this function in, and what exactly is `Wide::Lexer::TokenType::Identifier`?

Comment: @NicolBolas: It's in `Wide::Lexer::operator()()`, and `Wide::Lexer::TokenType` is an `enum`, where `Identifier` is one of the values.

Comment: Just to note, explicit enum qualification is Standard C++11 and VS has supported it as an extension since 2003, I think, or 2005. It's certainly in 2010.

Comment: Is `this` captured by `[&]` or does it need to be captured explicitly?

Comment: @K-ballo: I've no idea, but there are no references to `this` in the lambda, so I figured it wasn't important.

Comment: Could it be preprocessor clash? In that case, you'd like to look at line 121 after preprocessing

Comment: @sehe: I checked, and there are no clashing `#define`s.

Comment: @K-ballo: To answer your question, `this` is never implicitly captured, even with `&`.

Comment: @DeadMG: Are you using any function-scoped typedef's within the lambda?

Comment: @GMan: No, all type references are fully qualified.

Comment: @sehe: It seems to run just fine.

Comment: Eeee. Just to be sure, I'd probably make that `bug_workaround_type::Identifier` of some non-integral type (e.g. `void(*)(void)`?) instead of int, just to avoid the compiler actually _using_ it during code generation. I'd be very wary of wrong code generated here. Any idea, what circumstance triggered it? I couldn't reproduce it on VS2010 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel

Comment: @sehe: The project isn't the biggest, but it's not small enough for me to reconstruct it piece by piece. As for the type, the compiler doesn't seem to care- I changed it to the never-gets-old pointer-to-member-function, so I doubt that it's going to use that for anything anytime soon.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I tried to concoct a minimal working sample in order to compile on VS2010 and compiled the following without error.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_map>

namespace Wide { namespace Lexer {
    enum TokenType
    {
        OpenCurlyBracket,
        CloseCurlyBacket,
        Namespace,
        For,
        While,
        Do,
        Type,
        Identifier,
    };
} }

struct Token
{
    std::wstring Codepoints;
    Wide::Lexer::TokenType type;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Token> tokens;
    std::for_each(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), [&](Token& t) {
        static const std::unordered_map<std::wstring, Wide::Lexer::TokenType> mapping([]() -> std::unordered_map<std::wstring, Wide::Lexer::TokenType>
        {
            // Maps strings to TokenType enumerated values
            std::unordered_map<std::wstring, Wide::Lexer::TokenType> result;

            // RESERVED WORD
            result[L"namespace"] = Wide::Lexer::TokenType::Namespace;
            result[L"for"] = Wide::Lexer::TokenType::For;
            result[L"while"] = Wide::Lexer::TokenType::While;
            result[L"do"] = Wide::Lexer::TokenType::Do;
            result[L"type"] = Wide::Lexer::TokenType::Type;

            // PUNCTUATION
            result[L"{"] = Wide::Lexer::TokenType::OpenCurlyBracket;
            result[L"}"] = Wide::Lexer::TokenType::CloseCurlyBacket;
            return result;
        }());
        if (mapping.find(t.Codepoints) != mapping.end()) {
            t.type = mapping.find(t.Codepoints)->second;
            return;
        }
        t.type = Wide::Lexer::TokenType::Identifier; // line 121
    });
}
```

Could you bisect the minimum edit that show the problem, starting from this code?

Comment: I think it's quite safe to stick this one under "compiler bug".

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem right now. I used other types, but for your case it will be like this:

```
auto end_current_token = [&] {

    using Wide::Lexer::TokenType;           // <-- this line solves problem

    if (current != Wide::Lexer::Token()) {
        current.type = Wide::Lexer::TokenType::Identifier;
```

Now it compiles well.